# Bluetooth Low Energy data transmission on iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm recently working on a project which uses Bluetooth Low Energy. I implemented most of communication protocol, however I started having concerns, that actually I don't know how the data transmission works and if the solution that  I implemented is going to behave in the same way with all devices.

So my main concern is what data chunk is received when I get a notification from `peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:)`? Is it only as big as negotatiated MTU size? Or maybe iOS receives information about chunk size and waits to receive it all before triggering `peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:)`?

When a peripheral sends chunks let's say 100 bytes each, can I assume that I will get always in a single notification 100 bytes? Or could it be last 50 bytes from previous chunk and first 50 bytes from the next one? That would be quite tricky and hard to detect where is the beginning of my frame.

I tried to find more information in Apple documentation but there is nothing about it.

My guess is that I receive always a single state of characteristic. Therefore it would mean that chunks depend on implementation on peripheral side. But what if characteristic is bigger than MTU size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, keep in mind that sending streaming data over a characteristic is not what characteristics are designed for. The point of characteristics is to represent some small (~20 bytes) piece of information like current battery level, device name, or current heartbeat. The idea is that a characteristics will change only when the underly value changes. It was never designed to be a serial protocol. So your default assumption should be that it's up to you to manage everything about that.

You should not write more data to a characteristic than the value you get from `maximumWriteValueLength(for:)`. Chunking is your job.

Each individual value you write will appear to the receiver atomically. Remember, these are intended to be individual values, not chunks out of a larger data stream, so it would make no sense to overlap values from the same characteristic. "Atomically" means it all arrives or none of it. So if your MTU can handle 100 bytes, and you write 100 bytes, the other side will receive 100 bytes or nothing.

That said, there is very little error detection in BLE, and you absolutely can drop packets. It's up to you to verify that the data arrived correctly.

If you're able to target iOS 11+, do look at L2CAP, which is designed for serial protocols rather than using GATT.

If you can't do that, I recommend watching WWDC 2013 Session 703, which covers this use case in detail. (I am having trouble finding a link to it anymore, however.)

Comment: Thank you for valuable answer. That's what I thought that characteristics are not designed to stream data. However, there are some manufacturers which provide BLE with Serial Port Service like: https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/LowEnergySerialPortService_ProtocolSpec_%28UBX-16011192%29.pdf

Comment: I believe L2CAP is available in ios11+

Comment: Thank Paul; yes, you're right. I forgot that I was holding off because of iOS10.

Comment: @WojciechKulik Lots of people use GATT to stream data. I stream large files this way, and run a bidirectional serial protocol over GATT, too. Apple even used to have example code to walk you through it (if you can find the session I list above). It's just not *designed* for that purpose :D

Comment: Here is the sessions: http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/703xcx2xljtlq481grxurla4/703/703-HD.mov?dl=1

Comment: @RobNapier I watched this sessions but I don't see there anything about streaming data or sending large chunks. I have to support iOS 10, so what is the best approach to implement receiving large amount of data? Is there any other way than via notifications from characteristic?

Comment: I'm sorry; I really thought that was the one that talked about it. Maybe double-check the more recent one. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/712/  But as for transferring large chunks of data, that's it. You write on a characteristic and/or receive notifications on a characteristic. Chunking is up to you. And it's not particularly fast. You generally will want at least a checksum to make sure it all transferred correctly. And you'll either need to send a length at the beginning, or have an end marker.